# Wiring LED Halo Cup Lights To Existing Fixture

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, recessed-lighting, diy-vs-pro, fixtures

I took down a fluorescent Light fixture. To start the chain and install LED CUP Halo lights but there are 7 Wires total in the box and two sets of wires.

- 3 White wires in a bundle
- 3 Black wires in a bundle and
- one red single wire capped off.

There is not enough room in the box that comes with the halo to use that current fixture. What's the best way to connect to that fixture without having to use that current setup? Or is there a better way? I'm assuming one bundle of wires is switch power and one is the main wiring. All connected.

Comment: picture please so we can see it

Comment: What wires did you disconnect when you took down the fluorescent fixture?

Comment: Was the existing fixture using itself as the junction box, and all the wires entered the fixture directly, or is there another dedicated junction box in the ceiling?